# Stop performSelector:withObject:afterDelay for loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, for-loop, performselector

Here's a code snippet I'm trying to get to work, but its loop won't stop the way that I want it to:

```
 - (IBAction)methodName:(UIButton*)sender 
{
        [self loopMethod];
}

-(void) loopMethod
{

   for( int index = 0; index < loopLimit; index++ ) 
   {
        //code I want to execute
        [self performSelector:@selector(loopMethod) 
                   withObject:nil 
                   afterDelay:2.0];   
   }
}
```

The code just keeps looping even though I've made the for loop finite. What I want is for the code to execute, pause for two seconds, and then run the loop while the `int` value is less than the `loopLimit` I've set.

It's been hinted that this `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method may not be the right thing to use here but I'm not sure why or what is better to use here.

Any illuminating suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that the loop is running as quickly as possible, and the `performSelector:...` calls are happening at that speed. Then, at 2.0001, 2.0004, 2.0010, ... seconds later, `method` gets called.

The other thing (now that you've edited to make clear that the `performSelector:...` is ending up calling the same method that it's in, is that the value of your loop's `index` variable isn't saved between calls. Every time `loopMethod` is run, the code in the loop starts from the beginning: `index` is set to zero and counts up. That means that every time the method is run, you end up with `loopLimit` *new* calls pending, 2 seconds from then. Each one of those calls in turn spawns a new set, and so on, ad infinitum.

Every run of the loop is in fact finite, but the loop keeps getting run. You need some way to signal that the loop needs to stop, and you can't do that entirely within the loop method. You could put the counter (your `index` variable) into an ivar; that would make its value persistent across calls to `loopMethod`, but I think you want to look into [using an `NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/) that repeats:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(method:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

If you stick this into an ivar, you can keep track of how many times it fires and stop it later. There's a number of posts already on SO about updating text fields in a loop, using a timer like this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+update+text+field+timer

Comment: Orpheus, let me know if you need more detailed explanation. What's happening is completely clear, but I'm not sure how much you already know.

Comment: I've been coding for a month so this is all new to me! A more detailed explanation would be a great help.

Comment: @Orpheus: I've expanded a bit. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded explanation Josh. It's extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't run every 2 seconds is because you are running through the loop, and shooting off that selector after a 2 second delay. In other words, there is no delay in between the loop. If i had to guess, it probably waits 2 seconds, then fires `loopLimit` times, correct?

For your function to work the way you want it to, it would need to be recursive.

```
-(void) methodName
{
   if(index < loopLimit) {
    //code you want to execute
    [self performSelector:@selector(**methodName**) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];   
   }
   index++;
}
```

This is a pretty awkward way to do this. An `NSTimer` is typically what you would use here instead, then you can stop the timer when you are done.

In a function you start the timer like this:

```
[self setIndex:0];
[self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(method:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

then this method gets called every time:

```
-(void)method:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if(index >= loopLimit) {
         [[self timer] invalidate];
    }

    //Code you want to execute
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ColdLogic. I'm going to try both solutions I've been given let you know how it works out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: GL, let me know the results. One direction I would caution you is to go the NSTimer route. In is definitely more standard.